# Java port of Titlecase

Tags: java, android

I have a port of [titlecase, originally in Perl](https://github.com/ap/titlecase) and ported to other languages such as [JavaScript](https://github.com/ap/titlecase) and [Python](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~muffinresearch/titlecase.py/trunk/view/head:/titlecase/__init__.py).

```
import android.text.TextUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Titlecase {
    protected Titlecase() {}

    private static List<String> SMALL = Arrays.asList("a", "an", "and", "as", "at", "but", "by", "en", "for", "if", "in", "of", "on", "or", "the", "to", "v", "v.", "via", "vs", "vs.");
    private static Pattern ALL_CAPS = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Upper}\\p{Punct}]+");
    private static Pattern LOWER = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Lower}]+");
    private static Pattern CAMEL = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Lower}]+[\\p{Upper}]+");
    private static Pattern PUNCT = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}]+");

    public static boolean isShouting(String s) {
        Matcher $ = LOWER.matcher(s);
        return !$.find();
    }

    public static String get(String s) {
        List<String> processed = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] lines = s.split("\\n");
        for (String l : lines) {
            List<String> tc_line = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] words = l.split("\\s+");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                } else if (word.contains("-")) {
                    List<String> tc_dashes = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] dashes = word.split("-");
                    for (String d : dashes) {
                        tc_dashes.add(processWord(d));
                    }
                    tc_line.add(TextUtils.join("-", tc_dashes));
                } else if (word.contains("//") || '/' == word.charAt(0)) {
                    tc_line.add(word);
                } else if (word.contains("/")) {
                    List<String> tc_dashes = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] dashes = word.split("/");
                    for (String d : dashes) {
                        tc_dashes.add(processWord(d));
                    }
                    tc_line.add(TextUtils.join("/", tc_dashes));
                }
                else {
                    tc_line.add(processWord(word));
                }
            }
            if (tc_line.size() > 0) {
                tc_line.set(0, processWord(tc_line.get(0), true));
                tc_line.set(tc_line.size() - 1, processWord(tc_line.get(tc_line.size() - 1), true));
            }
            processed.add(TextUtils.join(" ", tc_line));
        }
        return TextUtils.join("\n", processed);
    }

    private static String processWord(String word) {
        return processWord(word, false);
    }

    private static String processWord(String word, boolean forceSmallToUpper) {
        if (word.contains("_") || word.contains("@")) {
            return word;
        }


        Matcher $ = CAMEL.matcher(word);
        if ($.find()) {
            return word;
        }

        $ = PUNCT.matcher(Character.toString(word.charAt(0)));
        if ($.matches()) {
            if (word.length() > 1) {
                return Character.toString(word.charAt(0)) +
                        processWord(word.substring(1), true);
            } else {
                return word;
            }
        }

        $ = ALL_CAPS.matcher(word);
        if ($.matches()) {
            if (word.contains(".")) {
                return word;
            } else {
                word = word.toLowerCase();
            }
        }

        if (word.length() > 3) {
            if (("`" == Character.toString(word.charAt(1)) ) ||
                    ("'" == String.valueOf(word.charAt(1))) ||
                    ("’" == String.valueOf(word.charAt(1)))) {
                word = Character.toString(word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() +
                        Character.toString(word.charAt(1)) +
                        Character.toString(word.charAt(2)).toUpperCase() +
                        word.substring(3);
                return word;
            }
        }

        if (!forceSmallToUpper && SMALL.contains(word)) {
            return word;
        }

        if (word.length() > 1) {
            word = Character.toString(word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() +
                    word.substring(1);
        } else {
            word = word.toUpperCase();
        }

        return word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a bit too idiomatically Perl to me when it comes to variable naming:

- `tc_lines` should be `tcLines` (or even something different, to make it easier to understand what it represents). Same for `tc_dashes`.
- `l` (in `for (String l : lines)`) could be `line`, no need to save 3 chars. ;)
- While Java allows for full Unicode identifiers, it's definitely non standard to name something `$`. At least if it's not something representing an amount of money.
- I would use static final variables for most of the String constants you have, like `"/"`

**processWord**

I personally prefer not to use a variables to hold an object if I'm using them in exactly one place:

```
public static boolean isShouting(String s) {
    Matcher $ = LOWER.matcher(s);
    return !$.find();
}
```

could be

```
public static boolean isShouting(String s) {
    return !LOWER.matcher(s).find();
}
```

and the same with other instances of the `$` variable. I just find it easier to read, but this might be just personal taste.

This here does not seem right:

```
if (("`" == Character.toString(word.charAt(1)) ) ||
                ("'" == String.valueOf(word.charAt(1))) ||
                ("’" == String.valueOf(word.charAt(1)))) {
```

Strings are objects and therefore the comparison will most probably fail. You could rewrite it as:

```
char second = word.charAt(1);
if (second == '`' || second == '\'' || second == '’') {
```

This:

```
       word = Character.toString(word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() +
                Character.toString(word.charAt(1)) +
                Character.toString(word.charAt(2)).toUpperCase() +
                word.substring(3);
```

could make use of a StringBuilder to prevent constant String allocation, and use the Character.toUpperCase methods to prevent even more unnecessary String creation:

```
    word = new StringBuilder(word.length())
        .append(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)))
        .append(word.charAt(1))
        .append(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(2)))
        .append(word.substring(3))
        .toString();
```

This:

```
    if (word.length() > 1) {
        word = Character.toString(word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() +
                word.substring(1);
    } else {
        word = word.toUpperCase();
    }
```

does exactly the same as this:

```
    word = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
```

given that substring will return the empty string if it's passed the total length of the string. It's smaller, maybe a bit clearer, and might even be more efficient given that it avoids an `if` (and the string addition of an empty string might be totally ignored during execution). You can also use a StringBuilder there, and use the same code for the part before where it matches with `PUNCT`.